# How do I get the value of the x coordinate and y coordinate separately from the bounding rectangle around my circle using the getBounds2D() method?

Tags: java, swing

That method gives the x coordinate, y coordinate, width and height of the rectangle, but I want the x coordinate and y coordinate only, and I want each of those separately?

Please could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense as the solution is trivial -- simply call the getter methods of the Rectangle2D object obtained. I'm confused as to where you're confused.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the helpful response. Yeah I got it now. As a complete beginner, sometimes I get confused with these things man. It isn't as trivial to me.

Comment: But you should know the basic steps of how to look for this information -- the Java API. In this situation go to the API, check what is returned by `getBounds2D()` and then check what methods are available to that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is trivial: Simply get the Rectangle2D returned from the `getBounds2D()` method and call `getX()` and `getY()` on it.

The heuristic on solving similar problems in the future is to learn to use the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html), search on the class of interest, here the Shape type, check out the [Shape API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). See that the `getBounds2D()` returns a `Rectangle2D`. Check out [its API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) and see what methods are available to it. Here it has useful methods from its parent class [RectangularShape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html), including `getX()` and `getY()`.